# Lost all hard disks partition and data

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, system-installation, data-recovery, data-loss

hard disk space lost when I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and also lost all partition and data
please help me out.
i was installing Ubuntu 14.04 accidentally LOST ALL DATA & drive partitions.
i have not try any software for recovery so please tell me how can i recovery all partitions back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no undelete command with Unix partitions
It is possible to reconfigure partition exactly as it was but since you installed 14.04 already, it is too late. All has been overwritten.